# Is it possible to inject a dependency of my mock into a class that belongs in a different package?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

My question is a little broad here so even ideas or approaches are good enough. The gist of what I am trying to do is, am trying to write tests for a class which down the stack makes a database call by creating a java [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) object. So I want to mock/inject my own connection here but the tricky part is this happens way down the call stack which actually takes me to a different package (which my project depends on). Here is a skeleton of the call stack.

```
Package A
Class One
  getLatestChanges()

  calls

Package B
Class Two
  getChanges()

  calls

Package B
Class Three
  getChanges()

  calls

Package C
Class Four
  getConnection() <= returns the Connection
```

I was wondering if I could use [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or something else to somehow trick Class Four's method getConnection() to return a different connection (am creating an in-memory database using H2 just for testing). The issue is, all the classes have been designed such that they don't take in dependencies but just create states within them.

The getConnection() is a private method:

```
private Connection getConnection() {
  return ConnectionFactory.getFactory().create().getConnection();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered carefully the difference between integration tests vs pure unit tests?  Seems like if you are allowing calls from A to B to C to D to the database, then you are trying to perform an integration test, in which case you should not be trying to mock out the database connection, but rather have a rollback-test instead.  If you really do want to pure unit test, then only test directly what your Class A method does and its interaction with direct collaborators (i.e. class B only).  You are free to either mock or not mock the collaborator.

Answer (score 1):

The simple but disappointing answer:
You can't **inject** anything that you can't simply populate "manually" otherwise.

My point is that, your problem is not really to have to *not bother about having some stuff initialised/injected only when they're ready/required* (which is the very purpose of the injection) as much as having to *simply substitute some part of one of your components*.

Also, if you're not using any dependency injection yet, I believe bringing in such framework only for tests feels... "meh". Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that tests aren't important: just that, would you **need** CDI, I'm pretty confident you'd rather have it for your actual project as well.

So maybe you don't need it.

---

Actually, maybe you just need to test your class `One` in the package `A` at this point (and testing the rest somewhere else, or assuming that the rest is working well (e.g.: the "rest" would be third party libraries).

In such case, would it be possible for you to simply mock `B.Two#getChanges()` so it responds with some dummy data that you control?

This would allow you to actually simply focus on testing that `A.One#getLatestChanges()` does what it's supposed to do with whatever it gets from `B.Two#getChanges()`, independently of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to alter one of the classes a little to make it testable, where you do that is up to you. If you really want to test class D, I'd suggest adding a setter to class D to make the connection injectable, and using PowerMock or creating a MockConnection class yourself and defining the behavior you want it to display.